# R split string at last whitespace chars using tidyr::separate

Tags: regex, r, dplyr, tidyr

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("AA","BB"),b=c("short string","this is the longer string"))
```

I would like to split each string using a regex based on the last space occuring.
I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df%>%
  separate(b,c("partA","partB"),sep=" [^ ]*$")
```

But this omits the second part of the string in the output. My desired output would look like this:

```
   a              partA  partB
1 AA              short string
2 BB this is the longer string
```

How do I do this. Would be nice if I could use tidyr and dplyr for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` by using the capture groups (`(...)`).  We match zero or more characters (`.*`) and place it within the parentheses (`(.*)`), followed by zero or more space (`\\s+`), followed by the next capture group which includes only characters that are not a space (`[^ ]`) until the end (`$`) of the string.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, b, into = c('partA', 'partB'), '(.*)\\s+([^ ]+)$')
#   a              partA  partB
#1 AA              short string
#2 BB this is the longer string
```

Answer (score 11):

You may turn the `[^ ]*$` part of your regex into a `(?=[^ ]*$)` non-consuming pattern, a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (that will not consume the non-whitespace chars at the end of the string, i.e. they won't be put into the match value and thus will stay there in the output):

```
df%>%
  separate(b,c("partA","partB"),sep=" (?=[^ ]*$)")
```

Or, a bit more universal since it matches any whitespace chars:

```
df %>%
  separate(b,c("partA","partB"),sep="\\s+(?=\\S*$)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wjpVA7/1) and its graph below:

[image]

Output:

```
   a              partA  partB
1 AA              short string
2 BB this is the longer string
```